# Examples of Normalized Semigroup of Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-lattices

In the theory of semigroups of bounded linear operators ${Z(t)}_{t\geq0}$, the normalized semigroups, $Z(t) : V\rightarrow V$ are defined as follows:
$$Z(t)e=e,$$ where $V$ is unital Banach Algebra and 'e' is the multiplicative identity function in $V$.

Now, I am interested to know some of the examples of such normalized linear operators that form a semigroup.

Comment: What is a multiplicative identity in a Banach space?

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly wrote Banach Space instead of  unital Banach Algebra $V$. The multiplicative identity in unital Banach Algebra is the element 1 $\in V$ such that $||1||=1$.

Comment: One set of examples from probability is given by the transition semigroups of markov processes with paths in $C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact space (this can be generalised a bit of course).